# onPageChanged Conditions are not loading

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension on a specific website it should show the popup.

The website list is more than 1000 and I cannot write condition one by one, That is why I'm getting data via GET request and parsing it and making condition based on that.

```
function conditions() {
  var conditionList = []
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vaibhavmule/ycinfo/master/ycstartup.json', true);

  request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      // Success!
      var ycStartups = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      Object.keys(ycStartups).forEach(function (key) {
        conditionList.push(
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { urlMatches:  key + '\\..*' }
          })
        )
      })
    }
  };

  request.send();

  return conditionList;
}

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
      {
        conditions: conditions(),
        actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
      }
    ]);
  });
});
```

Here is link to Github code: https://github.com/vaibhavmule/ycinfo/blob/master/background.js

Comment: "it should show the popup" - sounds like you want it to **open** the popup but it's not possible. The ShowPageAction action simply highlights the extension icon in the modern versions of Chrome (in the past it showed an icon inside the address bar), without even guaranteeing it'll appear in the toolbar if it's usually hidden in the overflow menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait till all the yc startup are fetched and then call `addRules` function. The approach I have taken here is to use promises, do it like this.

```
function conditions() {
  return fetch(`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vaibhavmule/ycinfo/master/ycstartup.json`)
    .then(function(res) {
    if (res.status === 200) {
      return res.json();
    }
    })
    .then(function(ycStartups) {
    console.log(ycStartups);
    return Object.keys(ycStartups).map(function (key) {
      return new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
        pageUrl: { urlMatches:  key + '\\..*a' }
      })
    });
    })
}

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    conditions().then(function(res) {
      chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
        {
          conditions: res,
          actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
        }
      ]);
    });

  });
});
```

here is my PR: https://github.com/vaibhavmule/ycinfo/pull/3

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, it is worked like champ, Accepting your PR.